# How to push many times and deploy once a day on openshift jenkins

Tags: php, jenkins, openshift

I am running a php application on openshift and it's live.
I'm using jenkins for continuous integration but I have an issue.

Everytime I push my changes to openshift's git repository, jenkins builds my code
and takes the app offline and deploys the new code before restarting the app.

I would like to push many times to jenkins and have it deploy and builds it hasn't yet
deployed once a day. How do I go about doing this.

The little I understand is that I'll need 2 jenkins jobs. One to receive a push, build it and store the build artifact. The other to run once a day to deploy and previous builds it hasn't already deployed. How do I go about setting up the second one
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the deployments feature, you can setup your code to not automatically get deployed on a git push, and then deploy it manually with a command.  This article should get you going with deployments: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/introduction-to-deployments-and-rollbacks-on-openshift

This command is what you will want to use:

```
rhc app-configure --no-auto-deploy
```

And then a combination of these commands to deploy:

```
rhc deployment-list
rhc deployment-activate <deployment id>
```